# Pronunciation style used in Hans Ørberg's Lingua Latina

Tags: pronunciation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In his book, Hans Ørberg uses macrons to show longer vowel sounds, but it's not clear to me if this is reconstructed, ecclesiastical, something else, or if there are even differences between those vowels in each style of pronunciation. An example from chapter two is the name Iulia: Iūlia / Iūliī.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, LLPSI doesn't require any particular pronunciation style: you're free to read the text in Reconstructed Classical, Ecclesiastical, Traditional English, or whichever you prefer!

However, the vowel length markings are generally associated with Reconstructed Classical pronunciation. In Classical times, the long vowels (*ā ē ī ō ū ȳ*) were literally pronounced for longer than the short ones (*a e i o u y*); there was *probably* also a difference in sound (though whether this was acceptable in high-class oratory or considered a Vulgar trait it unknown). In the Romance languages, the length difference eventually disappeared entirely, and the set of twelve monophthongs was reduced to seven.

So when mediaeval writers went back and tried to imitate the Classical style, they didn't really bother with the vowel lengths (since they weren't a familiar part of everyday speech). For the most part, *a* and *ā* were pronounced exactly the same, and the difference was only marked in writing when absolutely necessary (like to separate *Rōma* from *Rōmā*; the latter was often written "*Româ*", with a circumflex).

Later, linguists and classicists looked back at the evidence, and came to the conclusion that vowel length was important and deserved to be studied. To the Romans, it was an important distinction, and it separated various near-homophones (like *alium* "another", *ālium* "garlic", or *anus* "ring", *ānus* "old woman"). So vowel length has had a resurgence of popularity.

But the Ecclesiastical pronunciation, and most of the regional pronunciations like Traditional English, were codified long before that. They're less concerned with how the ancient Romans spoke and more concerned with how people have been speaking in more recent years. So (except for a few exceptions involving *e* and *o*) those pronunciations don't care about vowel lengths. If you're using one of those, you can safely ignore the long marks when reading.

P.S. For an extremely brief and simplified summary of vowels in Reconstructed Classical pronunciation, *ī i ē e ā a o ō u ū y ȳ* were something like `/iː ɪ eː ɛ aː a ɔ oː ʊ uː ʏ yː/`. If you're interested in digging into this further, feel free to ask another question!

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean - it's independent of the actual vowel sound itself. I'm in the very early stages of teaching myself, so I really want to try and get it "right" for myself now so I learn it from the start. I'm not very familiar at all with IPA phonemes, which adds another layer of challenge. Google helps, though. :) Your quick summary will help, though! For example, am I correct in understanding that the Reconstructed Classical pronunciation of _i_ when not using a macron (at least for Øsberg) is like the _i_ in _kit_. I'm thinking of the name from my original post _Iūlia_.

Comment: @Adam Basically! *i* without a macron is as in "kit", *ī* with a macron as in "machine". Annoyingly, Øsberg also writes `/j/` (the first sound in "yes") with an *i* instead of a *j* — in this case, the first *i* is actually a `/j/`, which is why it's more commonly spelled *Jūlia*.

Comment: Fortunately I don't find using _I_ instead of _J_ too hard to grasp, having learned that in school at some point. So Iūlia would be pronounced something like _Yoo - lih - ah_. `/ɪ/` followed  `/ɑː/` is a new combination for me.

Comment: @Adam Yep, pretty much. I'm half-remembering something about short vowels taking long quality when before another vowel, though I'd have to check my sources on that.

Comment: If that's the case it would make more sense to me in my limited experience with Latin pronunciation, since it would make that name _Yoo-lee-ah_, and Iūliī, _Yoo-lee-eee_ (extra _e_ to emphasize the long i).

Comment: Interestingly, [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/The_Latin_Language/Pronunciation) gives the pronunciation of each vowel as always the same, only changing in length.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you referring to when you say, "When mediaeval writers went back and tried to imitate the Classical style"?

Comment: @brianpck When mediaeval authors tried to write in what-we-would-now-call-Latin (imitating Cicero and Caesar), as opposed to what-we-would-now-call-Romance as spoken in day-to-day life, though at the time iirc they called both of them "Latin".

Comment: @Draconis I'm mostly confused by "went back." Latin never dropped out of educated usage, so the gradual loss of vowel length wasn't an incomplete reversion but rather a natural development.

Comment: @brianpck I may be misunderstanding, but I thought there was a significant gap between Classical Latin being a living language and it being brought back in educated writing (which is how we get things like *equus* `/ekwus/` that Cicero wouldn't have used).

Comment: @Draconis It was quite alive and well throughout all those centuries! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Latin#Important_medieval_Latin_authors

Comment: @Adam Wikibooks is right in suggesting you forget English vowels altogether - the only Latin vowel that coincides with any English vowel in the majority of pronunciations is the short /e/ in *pet*. Everything else you need to repeat by ear without reference to English. I'm not sure if there's a good reply with pronunciation resources around here, but you can start [here](http://sicerabibax.free.fr) - using "open in new tab" is necessary on most pages due to them being from another millennium. The quality differences existed but you won't get them right if you try using English vowels.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Visually, that site belongs in antiquity. I listened to the audio files on Wikibooks as well and found that I was generally close with most sounds to what they should be. One sound that I sometimes hear differently is -um and -us; it seems like it should always bee _oom_ and _oos_, though some recordings have it as _uhm_ and _uhs_, which I took as more of an accent then the actual correct sound.

Comment: @Adam Yes, Latin has no *uh* sound. *oos* might be fine - or might not be, depending on your accent - for the quality but not for the length, which needs to be as in *book*. What this also means that English has no sound for the long /u:/. The final /m/ is not pronounced as the English [m] but as nasalisation of the previous vowel. The Wikibooks recordings vary in quality from all right to less so, and always have an English accent. If there's more than one speaker, the other speaker from wiktionary is always wrong.

Comment: I noticed the disparity of recordings on Wikibooks. I'll give a listen tomorrow for the recordings on the site you linked. As a child of military parents, I moved around a lot in the US and heard a variety of different accents so I adapt pretty well to recognizing and imitating different pronunciations, at least within the microcosm of US English accents.

Comment: By the way, when you say _book_, the _oo_ in that for me with my native pronunciation is different than the _U_ sound in a word like "luna". I'm assuming you mean _oo_ like the latter, or in a word like "moon".

Comment: @Adam The general consensus, or at least what I learned, is that short ŭ is somewhat like English "book" while long ū is like English "moon" (except longer). I'm not sure that's still up-to-date, though, this was years ago.

Comment: @Adam All right, let's just say that General American English has no equivalent vowel either for the short or the long /u/ of Latin, even if we tried transcribing using the IPA. Even less good will come out of trying to approximate Latin sounds with English spellings with no reference to an exact accent. Neither the vowel in *book* nor in *moon* exists in Latin. Imitating the pronunciations you've heard and have engrained already is different than acquiring a completely new sound system in a language you've never heard before.